# Попадает ли элемент списка в интервал

Tags: python, numpy

Доброго времени суток!
Имеется два списка такого вида:

```
freqsdepth = [2,20,40,80,100,200,400,600]
surfs = [0, 58, 307, 908]
```

Требуется выяснить попадает ли каждый элемент из первого в списка в интервал, который в свою очередь состоит из второго списка, т.е. `0-58, 58-307, 307-908` 
Буду крайне благодарен, заранее спасибо!

Comment: брать интервал и проверять оператором `in` ? )

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч как выбрать интервалы, список и его длина может меняться

Comment: Как на счет использования Pandas вместо Numpy? И укажите с какой стороны (левой, правой) интервалы открыты? Например: `[0, 58), [58, 307), ...` или `(0, 58], (58, 307], ...`

Comment: @MaxU В данном случае не имеет значения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используя [pandas.cut()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html):

```
import pandas as pd

In [119]: df = pd.DataFrame({'col':freqsdepth})

In [120]: df
Out[120]:
   col
0    2
1   20
2   40
3   80
4  100
5  200
6  400
7  600

In [121]: df['new'] = pd.cut(df['col'], bins=surfs)

In [122]: df
Out[122]:
   col         new
0    2     (0, 58]
1   20     (0, 58]
2   40     (0, 58]
3   80   (58, 307]
4  100   (58, 307]
5  200   (58, 307]
6  400  (307, 908]
7  600  (307, 908]
```